# How to use ng-model in Angular.js?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I'm  new to  Angular.js . The problem is with my  ng-model and ng-option. I have a data which shows code number with  city  name in  my  dropdownlist. I have made some changes to  show only  the city and remove the numbers in the dropdown list and it works fine **Ex: CHENNAI**. But, if i use ng-model and show the value in my  Angular expression, still i'm  getting  the same data **EX: 0123 CHENNAI**. Using ng-model how can  i show only  the city name in the Angular expression i.e {{}}.

Here is the html:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Branch : <i class="mandate">*</i></label>
      <select class="form-control input-md" name='branchName' ng-model="query.branch.branchName" ng-options="branch.branchName as   showName(branch.branchName) for branch in baseBranches">
        <option value="" selected>-- Select Branch --</option>
      </select>
   <span class="error" ng-show="search_form.branchName.$error.required">Branch  is  required</span>
 </div>
```

And the script written to remove numbers:

```
$scope.showName = function(branchName){
   return branchName.replace(/\d+/g, '')
   //alert(branchName);
}
```

Please help from  this because i'm  new to  Angularjs.

Comment: what is space between ng-model syntax?

Comment: do you want only the text value to be binded or also the numeric value. Or you just want the Text value to be shown in the view and binding having numeric as well. Please explain?

Comment: Sry for the mistake have edited  now

Comment: @ Manish  I need to  show only  the Text value and remove the numbers.

Comment: So only the text value shoud appear in view and the the scope variable should have both numeric and text. Can you create a demo of this having data that populates options in a Fiddle or Plnkr

Comment: @ Manish  even the scope variable should also  be in  text  only  no  numeric.

Comment: @ Manish here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/Azyd4dJb4H6YnkGOwk8t?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want both model value and text value that is shown to be without the number i.e "123CHENNAI" as "CHENNAI" use the same "showName" function you have written for the model value too as shown below :

```
 <select class="form-control input-md" name='branchName' ng-model="query.branch.branchName" ng-options="showName(branch.branchName) as   showName(branch.branchName) for branch in baseBranches">
   <option value="" selected>-- Select Branch --</option>
 </select>
```

Fiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/derkoe/KN9xx/presentation/), Please check if that is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Change your data into like

```
$scope.array =[{
 number: 123,
 name: "abc"
},
{
 number: 123,
 name: "abc"
}]
```

Comment: @ Gourav the data is from  API

Comment: @ Gourav I have already  removed  the number  in the dropdown list  using this function $scope.showName = function(branchName){
   return branchName.replace(/\d+/g, '')
   //alert(branchName);
}

Comment: but  facing  an problem on  how to  show the same data in  my  Expression {{}} using  ng-model.

Comment: Actually you didn't mention that. It's okay.

Comment: This might help you [link] ( )

Comment: @ Gourav you mean like this ng-model="query.showName[branchName]"